# Tables design for big database with daily new data

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, datatable, bigdata

I have a big database with a table: products (having products.id as a primary key). I receive daily data about the performance of each product (Num of ordered items, revenue, product views…etc)

I’m wondering whether I should structure the database in a way that each product has its own table and each row represents a date

OR

Each date has a table then each row represents a product with it’s performance data

OR

Is there any other efficient way to it.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Metrics please and what do you intend to do with this data?

Comment: @P.Salmon I'll create charts representing some KPIs (avg. conversion rate, avg. Net Profit... etc.) with date range filter and other filters like (product_category)

Comment: Do you keep old data?  Or does each day's data replace the old data?  Whet do the `SELECTs` look like?

Comment: @RickJames Yes I keep the old data. I basically have 10 parameters (KPIs) to save for each product for each day. I need to be able to retrieve (SELECT) a specific value of parameter for a specific product in a specific day (800 products and increasing daily and 365 days of data history). I unfortunately don't have the SELECTs since I still didn't structure my database tables.

Answer (score 0):

One table, something like

```
CREATE TABLE mydata (
    the_day DATE NOT NULL,
    product_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    ket_profit ...,   -- maybe INT?  maybe FLOAT?
    conv_rate ...,    -- unless this is the quotient of two things
    kpi3 ...,   -- but use real name and datatype
    kpi4 ...,
    ...
    kpi10 ...,
    PRIMARY KEY(product_id, the_day)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

That looks like less than a million rows a year -- a medium-sized table.  The PK will make the query you sketched out run quite fast.